# How to set location query using react.router.dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router-dom

I am trying to set  location.query using react.router.dom v6. As I set my query inside service I can not use hook so I use
`const history = createBrowserHistory()`

This code is setting query, but if I change the page it will disappear. It will work if after setting the query I will refresh the page. In this case, the query will work fine. I think this is the issue of using router v6, I created a custom router but it didn't help. Maybe exist somehow to fix this?

history.ts

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()
export const getQueryPathname = (): string => history.location.pathname
export const setUrlQuery = <T>(urlQueryName: string, urlQuery: T): void => {
  const pathname = getQueryPathname()
  history.push({
    pathname: pathname,
    search: `?${urlQueryName}=${String(urlQuery)}`,
  })
}
```

Custom Router

```
import { History } from 'history'
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Router, RouterProps } from 'react-router-dom'

interface CustomRouterProps {
  history: History
  props?: RouterProps
}

const CustomRouter: React.FC<CustomRouterProps> = ({ history, ...props }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    action: history.action,
    location: history.location,
  })

  useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history])

  return <Router {...props} location={state.location} navigationType={state.action} navigator={history} />
}

export default CustomRouter
```

service where I use setUrlQuery

```
  testFunction(id: number): void {
    setUrlQuery('query', id)
    // some other logic
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook that ships with RRDv6 to read/set query string parameters?

Answer (score -1):

I am using `useHistory()` hook from `react-router-dom` and doing something like:

```
const history = useHistory();
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      queryParams.append('query', id)
      history.replace({ search: queryParams.toString() });
```

Comment: This is react-router v5, question asks for v6